# Duplicate MongoDB responses on multiple condition matches

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB and I have the following collection:

```js
>>> db.inventory.insertMany( [
   { item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] }
]);
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("5ff767c63484d0e87c8fdb6c"), 
        ObjectId("5ff767c63484d0e87c8fdb6d")
    ]
}
```

I know I can query the nested objects in the `instock` array and get the relevant documents. E.g.:

```js
>>> db.inventory.find( { 'instock.qty': { $lte: 10 } } );
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff767c63484d0e87c8fdb6c"),
    "item" : "journal",
    "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5.0 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15.0 } ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff767c63484d0e87c8fdb6d"),
    "item" : "notebook",
    "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 5.0 } ]
}
```

But now I would like to duplicate the returned documents if the `find` condition matches the document several times. Something like:

```js
>>> db.inventory.find( { 'instock.qty': { $lte: 20 } } );
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff767c63484d0e87c8fdb6c"),
    "item" : "journal",
    "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5.0 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15.0 } ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff767c63484d0e87c8fdb6c"),
    "item" : "journal",
    "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5.0 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15.0 } ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff767c63484d0e87c8fdb6d"),
    "item" : "notebook",
    "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 5.0 } ]
}
```

In this example, the first document is returned twice because the `{ 'instock.qty': { $lte: 20 } }` condition matches the document twice (for `{ "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5.0 }` and also `{ "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15.0 }`)

Is there a way to get such a behavior with MongoDB?

Thank you.

Comment: Why using network traffic and exercising db instead of duplicating documents on the client side? You have all data you need to do that

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy In order to use the Mongo pagination feature (skip, limit) on the duplicated results.

Comment: Does this approach solve for you? https://mongoplayground.net/p/btUCYw6F5ap

Comment: Or maybe you need this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/EO4bsxfXmbu